# Mismatch between column type in MySQL and Django model value

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a model class defined as follows:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    # ...
    spending = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    # ...
```

And populate it like so:

```
p = Person(
    # ...
    spending = str(row['spending'])
    # ...
)
p.save()
```

In which `row` is a pandas DataFrame row. What will the type of the field be in the database? What if the field is defined as `TextField` and what I insert is `int(row['spending')`?
Looking at the type in MySQL I can guess the defined field type is enforced. Will it still be the case if the column contains null values? For example, the field is of type numeric and we insert null values will it remain numeric or it will change to Text to accomodate the nulls?

Comment: maybe write code to test it and you will see answer. And check directly in database what you get. You can use tools like [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/)

Comment: I don't use Pandas, but I know that in a relational database, a column must have the same type on every row. So if you try to insert a string into an integer column, MySQL will cast the string to a numeric (unless there's an error). Likewise if you try to store a number in a string column, MySQL will cast the number to a string, which is just a string of digit characters.